# Where do you configure a UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an entity that represents a `Person` and a `UITableViewCell` subclass that displays a few attributes of said person.

The question is this: where do you *normally* configure (set the text, picture, etc) the table cell? Do you:

A) Configure it in the `UITableViewController` subclass while implementing `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

B) Pass the Person object into the `UITableViewCell` subclass and let the subclass configure itself?

C) Something entirely different?

### Bonus Points

If you answered with option A, what about this?

Let's say that for the first row in the table view, I need to bold all of the labels' text. Does that change your opinion at all? You see what I'm getting at here, if you configure the cell in the view controller, the view controller will become bloated with information it doesn't *really* need. But, if you put all the configuration inside of the table cell subclass, you lose some reusability. It is definitely a trade-off, but I'm wondering what most engineers choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "configure"? Do you mean adding the Person's data to the cell? I would do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which is usually part of the view controller (it is common to set the delegate of a table view to the view controller). The Person's data is ideally part of some model in your application. You can fetch the Person for the cell by using the index path, something like

```
Person *personForThisCell = [SomeModel getPersonAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

And then use that data to set the values of the cell.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by configure. See my "bounus points" edit. Does that change your opinion?

Comment: No. The ViewController can control elements of the view. Changing the style of a custom UI cell is it's responsibility. I try to stay away from subclassing UI elements.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your interface builder and select the cell. Using the inspector, link your cell agains your custom `UITableViewCell`.

[image: Inspector]

After that, instantiate your cell at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `UITableViewCell`, configure it and voilá.

Then, answering your comment:

Link the cell items to properties in the header of your Custom cell.
[image: link cell]

Let's say I created the property `UILabel cellTitle` in this example, so when I instantiate the cell at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, then I simply have to set the text for this property.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"pedidosCell"; //the same at the nib!
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.cellTitle.text = @"This is my cell title";
    // Using your Person object, that should be available here.
    cell.cellTitle.text = [Person name];

    return cell;
}
```

As for the bolding, you should stick with option A. It's an uncommon task to load data inside a `UITableViewCell` as it should be really fast to deal with the scrolling. Placing data inside of it won't work as Apple intended.

Of course you can make the cell aware of its location, by passing the `indexPath.row` to it, and than set the text to bold when needed. I don't know how this would play along with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Comment: Thanks, I know how to assign the subclass to the Nib. I'm talking about actually using a subclass to configure the cell or doing it in the table view's delegate.

Comment: Well, you should definitely pass the `person` object to the `DataSourceDelegate`, as the cell should be agnostic to its data.

Answer (score 2):

My normal approach is sort of a combination of A) and B)...

I use a category to add a `value` property to UITableViewCell. Then I create one or more subclasses of UITableViewCell, one for each type of row/value I want to display.

In my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of my data source, I dequeue/alloc a cell of the appropriate subclass and set `value` to the value to be displayed for that row.

Maybe someone else can help with using `UITableViewController`--I personally don't find it very useful. I usually just subclass UIViewController for each type of view I am displaying.. If that view contains a table view, I give my view controller a `tableView` outlet. This is similar to subclassing UITableViewCell for each type of cell I need.

Comment: Then, inside the table cell subclass, you actually place the data into the respective labels and such? What do you actually gain by using the category as opposed to an actual data structure included in the interface?

Comment: Yes, each cell subclass configures itself appropriately when `value` is set. Not sure what you mean by "actual data structure included in the interface".. If you mean what I think you mean, it means your data source code can be generic (`cell.value = valueForRow`) without writing special cases for different types of values. That's easy to write and maintain.

Comment: Agreed with this, I almost never use UITableViewController, and the category value on a UITableViewCell subclass approach sounds useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've started doing B (it just seems so irresistible), and I've yet to have a problem with it.

How I do it is the cell subclass has a weak reference to the model object. The Controller gives it the reference and it configures its attributes for display in the setRefence: method.

The cell subclass will only ever be used to display model items. This means my controller code is nice and clean (by which I mean small and simple), it means cell variants are easy to make and plugin, and actually you can then start to generalise this further and control your displays with subclasses that simply add the required differences in configuration. An interesting app with multiple tables each with specific cells becomes much less code - the general controller can be used, and the cell subclass and model contain their specifics.

I can't see a downside yet.

"But what if you wanted to reuse that class in another project" - I'd reuse the pattern, not the code.

"But you are tightly coupling a display object with the data it displays" - so what? They work in tandem - the Controller sets up the relationship and coordinates them - that is what it is for. Let your Views reference their Models.

(I'm posting here because I'd like to know that if this approach is wrong (and I've seen it listed as a sin) then WHY is it wrong?).

Comment: Did you have any luck finding an answer to this? Has your mind changed over the years? I agree 100% with your answer. I have yet to see a downside

Comment: @NumanTariq Well it's not something I have specifically pondered much since but no, looking above I agree with this and still do it. And projects I have taken over from others with more complicated approaches I found more difficult to maintain, so I stand by what I said here. In general whenever I detect code that is doing something similar to something I already have, I generalise it. And I let my views configure themselves from a Model reference :)